# Filter a DVWP based on currently logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, filter

I have a sharepoint list which lists issues.
 There are 4 people(not fixed) from separate groups(say A,B,C and D) responsible for each issue.
 Now I've a requirement according to which,

1. I'll have to design a simple dashboard(which I'm doing using a DVWP) to list the issues according to the issue which the currently logged in user is responsible for.
2. Also, there is a group E which is the group with the highest permissions and will be able to see all the issues with all the users responsible for them.

I've no idea how to do this.

Can this be done OOB or do I need to use XSLT(xsl:if) in SP designer? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below link. It shows how to Filter DVWP based on Current User.

http://www.hornerit.com/2010/08/filtering-data-view-web-part-to-current.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. That solves the first part of the question. I wanna know how to let the people who belong to the 'E' group (which you can consider it as an administrator group) see the entire DVWP without any filteration.

Comment: Is your 'E' group has custom rights(rights you have created) or SharePoint default rights like Contribute, Approve, Full Control??

Comment: Default rights... Full Control.

Comment: Here in this link it has shown different permission levels that can be used in XSLT. based on filtering you can achieve your goal. Hope it might Help.

http://shbdev.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/how-to-conditionaly-format-xslt-in-data-view-based-on-user-permissions-ifhasrights/